# Get sum of range in one cell

Tags: excel

I want to have a formula that calculates the sum of a given range.

Say I have `1,5` in cell `A1`. I want a formula to calculate `1+2+3+4+5`.
And maybe in a more advanced fashion, I would like to enter `1,5;6,3;1,4;...` and have it calculate `(1+2+3+4+5)+(6+5+4+3)+(1+2+3+4)`.

There won't be any negative numbers.

Is this somehow possible in Excel? For the range `6,3`, it's probably easiest to get the lower number and count up to 6.

Comment: Look up [*arithmetic progression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), the article in Wikipedia gives you a close-form formula for its sum.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you for the article. I do know how to calculate it, but how would one put this as a formula? How do I tell excel to take two integers separated by a comma and then another range separated by a semicolon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [user-defined function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx) that does what you want.  It works for negatives as well.  There is no error checking, e.g., for letters in the cell, more than one comma between semicolons (the first will generate a #VALUE error anyways).

Enter this function in a module in your workbook or in an addin:

```
Function AddSubstringProgressions(CellContent As String)
Dim Progressions As Variant
Dim Progression As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Total As Long
Dim Stepwise As Long

Progressions = Split(CellContent, ";")
For i = LBound(Progressions) To UBound(Progressions)
    Progression = Split(Progressions(i), ",")
    If Val(Progression(LBound(Progression))) > Val(Progression(UBound(Progression))) Then
        Stepwise = -1
    Else
        Stepwise = 1
    End If
    For j = Progression(LBound(Progression)) To Progression(UBound(Progression)) Step Stepwise
       Total = Total + j
    Next j
Next i

AddSubstringProgressions = Total
End Function
```

Call it like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you make it so you can call a macro as a regular formula on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @JackRadcliffe, see the User-Defined Function link at the beginning of the answer.  Basically, just paste it into a normal module.

Comment: Best answer so far, but can be optimised: you don't need to loop `Progression`.  Use `Total = Total + (Val(Progression(0)) + Val(Progression(1))) / 2 * WorksheetFunction.Max(Val(Progression(0)), Val(Progression(1)))`

Comment: @DougGlancy Nice. I just realized though that if I only have one pair, say `1,10` it gets converted into `1,1`. How do I have to format them, so that it doesn't get converted into `1,1`. I can certainly do `1,10;0`, but that just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @cherrun Is "," the decimal point for you?  On my US computer, if I enter "1,10", with no quotes, it's read as a string and isn't truncated.  But if I were to enter "1.10", with "." being the US decimal point, it would convert to "1.1".  If that's the issue, then you'll need to format the cell as text, or change the comma separator to something that's not part of a number.

Answer (score 1):

For a worksheet function approach you could try one of the following:

1. *Basic case* eg A1  = `1,5` or `6,3`

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",":"))))
   ```
2. *General case* eg A1 = `1,5;6,3;1,4`.

   Define the name `A =EVALUATE("{"&A1&"}")` and then enter:

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(ABS(MMULT(A^2,{1;-1}))/2+A)/2
   ```

*Update*. A short VBA udf based on the method above...

```
Function SumSeries(Val As String)
SumSeries = Evaluate("SUM(ABS(MMULT({" & Val & "}^2,{1;-1}))/2+{" & Val & "})/2") 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
Sub addRange()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i <= count
        Dim low As Integer
        Dim high As Integer
        low = Mid(Range("A" & i), 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(",", Range("A" & i)) - 1)
        high = Mid(Range("A" & i), Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(",", Range("A" & i)) + 1, Len(Range("A" & i)))
        If (low > high) Then
            Dim copy As Integer
            copy = low
            low = high
            high = copy
        End If
        Range("B" & i) = adder(low, high)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function adder(low As Integer, high As Integer) As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer
    sum = 0
    Do While low <= high
        sum = sum + low
        low = low + 1
    Loop
    adder = sum
End Function
```

This assumes that you have values like `2,5`, `6,4`, `1,8`, and others in cells A1:An.  It doesn't work for values like `2,5;6,4` as you describe to be the more advanced function, but it gets the job done for the basic ones.